# Issue with Simple Injector while using with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am having issue using Simple Injector with WebAPI project that gets created default with VS 2015. 
I am having the `AccountController` having the below constructor

```
public AccountController()
{
}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}
```

In order to register these I used the below code in Simple Injector

```
// Create the container.
var apiContainer = new Container();
apiContainer.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
apiContainer.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior = new ConstructorBehavior();

//register the classes that we are going to use for dependency injection            
apiContainer.Register<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(() => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()),Lifestyle.Scoped);
apiContainer.Register<IDataProtector>(() => new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"),Lifestyle.Transient);            
apiContainer.Register<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>(Lifestyle.Transient);
apiContainer.Register<ITextEncoder, Base64UrlTextEncoder>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
apiContainer.Register<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

//apiContainer.RegisterCommonClasses();

//register the webapi controller
apiContainer.RegisterWebApiControllers(configuration);
```

but after this I am getting the warning message that says

> [Disposable Transient Component] `ApplicationUserManager` is registered as transient, but implements `IDisposable`.

Can someone Please help me with this how to resolve this ? With Default Web api project with VS 2015 it adds Account controller and that use ApplicationUserManager and has below details

```
public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
    : base(store)
{
}

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
```

Another issue I am getting as below

The constructor of type `HttpConfiguration` contains the parameter with name 'routes' and type `HttpRouteCollection` that is not registered. Please ensure `HttpRouteCollection` is registered, or change the constructor of `HttpConfiguration`.

This is with the `HelpController` as it uses the below details:

```
public HelpController()
    : this(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
{
}

public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    Configuration = config;
}
```

Comment: There is a pretty good walkthrough of how to set this up [here](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) .

Comment: You can read about the warning [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/disposabletransientcomponent.html). Either you register `ApplicationUserManager` as scoped, or you refactor it, so it doesn't require to implement `IDisposable`.